# Business user templating language for Java

Tags: java, templating-engine

I'm looking for a secure templating language for Java that business users can use.

When I say secure I mean you can't enter in something that will take down the server or hog a thread.

Ideally I would like looping and conditions but for looping I don't want them enter an infinite loop or something like 1 to 3 billion counter.

Know of any libraries (I'm hoping to avoid having modify any of templating evaluators like Velocity)

Comment: Hmm http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/util/introspection/SecureIntrospectorImpl.html

Comment: Consider something like mustache; any template library that can evaluate Java has the potential to cause problems.

Comment: Also found: http://code.google.com/p/jmte/ . But there is no release yet.

Comment: Looks like a winner: http://code.google.com/p/hapax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up picking [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/). I chose the [Java implementation](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java) mainly because Scalate seems to have many, many dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered MVEL? It is fast, small, embeddable, and pretty easy to integrate. It allows you to setup all data to be operated on by the interpreter, which is great for security. And its syntax is expandable, so if you don't like the default's you can always come up with your own.

http://mvel.codehaus.org/

Comment: Looks like a possibility although it also looks like there templating language has been rewritten. Also it looks like I would have to do lots of work to secure it.